# Wubi after windows 8 reset

Tags: windows

I have windows 8 running on my pc and ubuntu installed through wubi. What will happen to my ubuntu if i reset my windows 8. (Resetting windows 8 uninstalls all 3rd party applications, will that delete ubuntu files?)

Answer (score 0):

[How to restore, refresh or reset your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

> Warning:
>
> All of your personal files will be deleted and your settings will be
>   reset. Any applications that came with your PC will be reinstalled,
>   but all other applications will be removed.

is it enough for your question?

Comment: i have installed ubuntu through wubi.exe.  will ubuntu also be get deleted after reseting windows?

Comment: of course the answer is Yes, my buddy.

Comment: thnx.. is there a way I could save it?